# How can I just use a bootstrap css plugin with material UI without installing the complete bootstrap (ngx-bootstrap) package in angular 6?

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular-material, angular6

Can i just use a bootstrap CSS file without installing the complete package in my angular 6 project. I am using material UI with angular. Now i am afraid if i use material UI with bootstrap , what would/might be happened ? 
How will UI plugins works ? Either it would raise a contradict or working fine.